# Left Join with Distinct Clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my insert query.

```
INSERT INTO /*+ APPEND*/ TEMP_CUSTPARAM(CUSTNO, RATING)
SELECT DISTINCT Q.CUSTNO, NVL(((NVL(P.RATING,0) * '10.0')/100),0) AS RATING
FROM TB_ACCOUNTS Q LEFT JOIN TB_CUSTPARAM P
ON P.TEXT_PARAM IN (SELECT DISTINCT PRDCD FROM TB_ACCOUNTS)
AND P.TABLENAME='TB_ACCOUNTS' AND P.COLUMNNAME='PRDCD';
```

In the previous version of the query, `P.TEXT_PARAM=Q.PRDCD` but during insert to `TEMP_CUSTPARAM` due to violation of unique constraint on `CUSTNO`.

The insert query is taking ages to complete. Would like to know how to use distinct with `LEFT JOIN` statement.

Thanks.

Comment: Practice with the SELECT part. (And when finished do the INSERT with SELECT.) Can you add some sample table data and the SELECT's expected result? (As well formatted text.)

Comment: Change that inner Select into Inner join and you should be good to go

Comment: Any chance that you missing a predicate on Q.CUSTNO in the ON clause? There is no column from the table Q referenced there....

Comment: 1. You shouldn't use `DISTINCT` inside `IN`. 2. You shouldn't use string literals for numbers (`'10.0'`). 3. `DISTINCT` is something rarely needed; are you sure there can be duplicate entries for a customer rating?

Comment: Yes there are duplicate entries, because TB_ACCOUNTS contain duplicate customer numbers due to one customer having multiple accounts.

Answer (score 7):

```
 SELECT T1.Col1, T2.Col2 FROM  Table1 T1
  Left JOIN 
(SELECT Distinct Col1, Col2 FROM Table2
) T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing criteria to join TB_ACCOUNTS records with their related TB_ACCOUNTS/PRDCD TB_CUSTPARAM records and thus cross join them instead. I guess you want:

```
INSERT INTO /*+ APPEND*/ TEMP_CUSTPARAM(CUSTNO, RATING)
SELECT DISTINCT 
  Q.CUSTNO, 
  NVL(P.RATING, 0) * 0.1 AS RATING
FROM TB_ACCOUNTS Q 
LEFT JOIN TB_CUSTPARAM P ON  P.TEXT_PARAM = Q.PRDCD
                         AND P.TABLENAME = 'TB_ACCOUNTS' 
                         AND P.COLUMNNAME = 'PRDCD';
```

Answer (score 0):

If the query is *taking ages* to complete, check first the execution plan. You may find some hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975406/how-to-describe-performance-issue-in-relational-database?answertab=oldest#tab-top) - If you see a cartesian join on two non-trivial tables, probably the query should be revisited.

Than ask yourself what is the expectation of the query.

Do you expect one record per `CUSTNO`? Or can a customer have more than one rating?

One reting per customer could have sense from the point of business. To get unique customer list with rating

1) first get a UNIQUE CUSTNO - note that this is in generel not done with a DISTINCT clause, but if tehre are more rows per customer with a filter predicate, e.g. selecting the most recent row.

2) than join to the rating table